# How to open a modal window the MVVM way

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm still trying to get a grip with WPF and MVVM and stumbled upon questions, where the easy way seems to violate the MVVM rules.

As far as I understood it, in MVVM the view model is not allowed to know about the view. So if I put views and view models in different assemblies, the view model assembly is not allowed to reference the view assembly.

So, here are my questions:

1. Let's say I have a MainView and a corresponding MainViewModel. The MainView has a button that is supposed to close the window and do some serious stuff before closing (for instance saving data and configurations).
   This button is bound to a CloseCommand in the MainViewModel, but how do I know in the MainViewModel which view to close.
   My easy (and wrong) ways would be either to give the MainViewModel an instance of the MainView on initialisation or to give the view-to-close as a command parameter.
   But both solutions violate the MVVM rule.
2. Let's say my MainView contains a TextBox bound to a string property of my MainViewModel. If the text, the user types in the TextBox, isn't unique enough, I'd like to open a new modal window in which the user can select his input out of various choices.
   To open a modal window in WPF you have to put the MainView in the `Owner` property of the new window. Therefore you need a reference to the MainView in the MainViewModel.
   Same problem exists, if you try to show a modal message box (a message box that is tied to the parent window and can't be put behind the parent window through mouse clicks or other user actions).

So, how is one supposed to do actions in the view model when you need knowledge about the view?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should have one `ViewModel` instance instantiated for each `View` - and the `ViewModel` can legally reference the `View` instance provided it's abstracted away through some interface (for example).

Comment: Also, you don't have to necessarily be so dogmatic about MVVM - it's okay to take shortcuts. The "gift" of MVVM whereby you're free to outright replace the View completely without it affecting the rest of the system (e.g. copy+paste a WPF MVVM into ASP.NET MVC) isn't really true: MVVM is (ironically) tightly-coupled to WPF.

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems that you wish to close the main window, and that is perfectly fine. As many things, this can be solved with a new level of abstraction. Lets say you have an interface called `IApplication` with a method `Close()`. And then lets say you have an implementation of the interface that might look something like:

   ```
   class ApplicationWrapper : IApplication
   {
       public void Close()
       {
           Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
       }
   }
   ```

   Couldn't you inject the `IApplication` interface in the view model and call its `Close` method from the command?
2. I would propose [MVVM Dialogs](https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/mvvm-dialogs), but I am biased since I also am the author.